# Cloning attachment from Email Object to Case Object

Tags: apex, case, attachment, email2case, emailmessage

I have the following Apex Trigger on the EmailMessage object (cases to email):

```
trigger EmailMessageTrigger on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    List<CaseComment> CaseComments = new List<CaseComment>();
    List<Attachment> Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    for (EmailMessage e : Trigger.New) {
        CaseComments.add(new CaseComment(CommentBody=e.FromName +' has added an email to the case: \n https://gnerb-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/'+e.Id,
                             ParentId=e.parentId));

        for (attachment a : e.attachments) {
            Attachment newFile = a.clone();
            newfile.ParentId = e.ParentId;
            Attachments.add(newFile);
        }
    }

    insert CaseComments;
    insert Attachments;
}
```

I need the email attachments to be cloned and attached to the email's parent case. I used the code from:

[Copying attachments from object to object trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42700/copying-attachments-from-object-to-object-trigger)

As an example and it doesn't seem to work. No errors are thrown or recorded to the log. I also tried putting the insert lines into a try/catch block to grab errors and no errors were produced. The case comment is added as desired.

**EDIT:**

Adding:

```
System.debug(e.attachments.size());
```

Outputs: 0

I tried to modify the for loop to the following:

```
    for (EmailMessage e : [SELECT Id, FromName, ParentId, (SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Attachments)
    FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id in :Trigger.New]) {
```

Unfortunately, it still shows 0.

Comment: First of all, the attachments (or any sobject) related list won't be in the scope of the trigger.new - they have to be queried for as you noted in your edit.  But more importantly, SFDC can't insert the Attachment until the after insert of `EmailMessage` is finished.  You'll need a trigger on Attachment that understands parentId being of sobjecttype EmailMessage

Comment: That makes sense; it's pretty much the exact opposite of what I wanted to do though. It just adds another piece to the puzzle. If that's the only option it's easy enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is based on crop1645's comment to the question:

```
trigger CaseAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {
    Set<Id> Parents = new Set<Id>();
    List<Attachment> newFiles = new List<Attachment>();

    for (attachment a : Trigger.New) {
        Parents.add(a.parentId);
    }

    for (EmailMessage e : [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id in :Parents]) { //loop through unique parents
        for (Attachment a : Trigger.New) {
            if (e.Id == a.ParentId) {
                Attachment newFile = a.clone();
                newFile.ParentId = e.ParentId;
                newFiles.add(newFile);
            }
        }
    }

    Insert newFiles;
}
```

This appears to be working in my tests.

Comment: Did this work for you ? I have a similar requirement and my trigger/handler is not getting invoked when attachments are created via an email. There is an active platform issue logged for this :  [**Trigger on Attachment does not fire when attachment is created via Email**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YTEAA2)

Comment: Yes this worked for me but this was 3 years ago. It's entirely possible that the issue has been reintroduced. I no longer work for the company that I wrote this code for so I cannot tell you if it is working at present.