# Converting Apex Trigger to a Class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

Please excuse any misstatements or blunders in my comments as I'm VERY new to Apex development. However, I've found code for a trigger that allows me to copy/clone attachments from a custom object (sales invoices) to a parent object (account).  However, I've been told that it's best practice to split this into an Apex Class with a simple Trigger calling the Class.  Herein is where my Apex development skills are severely lacking.

My existing Trigger code is (shamelessly re-used from here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/44184/28717:

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsToAccount on Attachment (after insert) {

// collect a set of Sales Invoices 'parent' IDs from the attachments inserted
Set<Id> serviceInvoiceIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {

    // only collect those that are for the c2g__codaInvoice__c object (others can be ignored)
    if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == c2g__codaInvoice__c.getSObjectType()) {
        serviceInvoiceIds.add(file.ParentId);
    }
}

if(!serviceInvoiceIds.isEmpty()) {

    // find the Account to which the c2g__codaInvoice__c relates
    Map<Id,c2g__codaInvoice__c> serviceInvoiceMap = new Map<Id,c2g__codaInvoice__c>([Select c2g__Account__c From c2g__codaInvoice__c Where Id IN :serviceInvoiceIds]);

    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    for (Attachment file : Trigger.new) {
        Attachment newFile = file.clone();
        newFile.ParentId = serviceInvoiceMap.get(file.ParentId).c2g__Account__c;
        attachments.add(newFile);
    }
    // finally, insert the cloned attachments
    insert attachments;
}
}
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos for trying to code cleaner. I have not tried to optimize your trigger, but here is how to split it into a new class.

Your trigger would look like this:

```
trigger AttachmentTriggers on Attachment (after insert) {
   AttachmentTriggerHandler.copyAttachmentsToAccount(trigger.new);

}
```

And your class like that:

```
public class AttachmentTriggerHandler {
  public static void copyAttachmentsToAccount(List<Attachment> attachs) {
     // collect a set of Sales Invoices 'parent' IDs from the attachments inserted
     Set<Id> serviceInvoiceIds = new Set<Id>();
     for(Attachment file : attachs) {
       // only collect those that are for the c2g__codaInvoice__c object (others can be ignored)
       if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == c2g__codaInvoice__c.getSObjectType()) {
         serviceInvoiceIds.add(file.ParentId);
       }
     }

     if(!serviceInvoiceIds.isEmpty()) {
       // find the Account to which the c2g__codaInvoice__c relates
       Map<Id,c2g__codaInvoice__c> serviceInvoiceMap = new Map<Id,c2g__codaInvoice__c>([Select c2g__Account__c From c2g__codaInvoice__c Where Id IN :serviceInvoiceIds]);

       List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

       for (Attachment file : attachs) {
         Attachment newFile = file.clone();
         newFile.ParentId = serviceInvoiceMap.get(file.ParentId).c2g__Account__c;
         attachments.add(newFile);
       }

       // finally, insert the cloned attachments
       insert attachments;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sebastian, thank you very much!  It's almost scary how close I got in my attempts (missing a variable name).  The only thing I had to change from your example above is to make it a "public static void" method.

Comment: That one was a stupid one. :) Just fixed so whoever looks at this next gets the right answer. I am glad it worked! Don't forget to upvote!

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the generic parts in your Apex trigger
2. Move all the common part to a class
3. Make it a static method if you are trying to use it as utility (without creating an instance)

Here we don't require any information more than serviceInvoiceIds from this trigger

So lets write a class

```
Class MyClass {
  Public static void execute( Set<Id> serviceInvoiceIds) {
Do all the logic here 
  Starting from the line which says
if(!serviceInvoiceIds.isEmpty()) {
......
}
}
}
```

I am leaving the interesting part of naming things and implementation to you. Hope you got the idea.